# Cerrar pestaña/navegador mediante código o tarea programada

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un script que se conecta a un server con `JavaScript`, luego me redireja un `PHP` y hace **X** procedimientos, abro dicho script cada **X** minutos con un *batchFile* y lo ejecuto con *Windows Task*, sin embargo me quedan las pestañas del navegador abiertas y quisiera cerrarlas, ¿cómo lo hago? ya sea *Window.Close* no me funciona porque no fue invocada con *Window.Open*

Comment: Hasta donde he visto en stackoverflow no se puede manipular otras ventanas usando javascript. Quizas (segun lei) se pueda usando el localstorage o cookies

Comment: O sea, según entiendo, todo eso es para poder ejecutar un script php determinado. Quizás deberías intentar ejecutar ese script php pero por línea de comandos, sin necesitar abrir un navegador.